# The name TimeLeft does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, integer, public

## **This question has been closed.**

This is different from the other questions I've seen related to this. I have two forms in my Mario game, right? I set a public integer in one of them, GameGUI.cs. In TimerStatus.cs I want to display this variable but it says the message "The name TimeLeft does not exist in the current context."

Here's some of the code.

```
public partial class TimerStatus : Form
{
    int TimerSecondsLeft = TimeLeft * 0.6;
    public TimerStatus()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TimerStatus_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "You have " + TimeLeft + " seconds remaining.";
    }
}
```

This is the code where TimeLeft is stored.

public partial class GameGUI : Form
    {
        public int TimeLeft = 400;
        bool right, left;
        bool isFacingLeft = false;
        bool jump;
        int G = 16;
        int Force;
        int WalkSpeed = 1;
        int Score = 0;
        int Lives = 3;

```
    bool isWalkFrameOne = false;
    byte animTime = 4;

    public GameGUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Remember that they're in two different forms.

Thanks to anyone who can help. :)

Comment: where you have declared the variable TimeLeft?

Comment: Making a field public only means you can access it from anywhere using an **object containing the field**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :** You are trying to access the `TimeLeft` as if it was declared in the same class. inorder to access the variables declared in outside class you need their class instance member or if they are declared as `static` you can access using their `classname`.

**Note:** you need to declare variables as `static` which belong to whole class.

**Solution:** in your program your `TimeLeft` variable seems tobe a classlevel variable so you can Declare your `TimeLeft` variable as static in your `GameGUI` class file.
so that you can access it from other classes using its classname.

Try This:

```
public partial class GameGUI : Form
{
    public static int TimeLeft = 400;
    bool right, left;
    /*remaining code here*/
}
```

Access it using its classname `GameGUI`

```
public partial class TimerStatus : Form
{
    int TimerSecondsLeft = GameGUI.TimeLeft * 0.6;
    public TimerStatus()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TimerStatus_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "You have " + GameGUI.TimeLeft + " seconds remaining.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access TimeLeft variable in another class directly. You need to access it using class object or with the class name, if it is static.

```
public partial class GameGUI : Form
{
    public static int TimeLeft = 400;
    .
    .
    .//your code
}
```

Now you can call it directly using class name as:

```
GameGUI.TimeLeft
```